# In the proof of Theorem 7.16 Croom, Principles of Topology; trouble with $f^{-1} ( f(q^{-1}(U))) = q^{-1}(U)$

Tags: general-topology

I have problem for understanding proof of Theorem 7.16, in Croom, Principles of Topology.

The statement is following

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous function from $X$ onto $Y$. In order that the natural correspondence $h: X/ \sim \rightarrow Y$ defined by $h([x]) = f(x)$, $x\in X$ be a homeomorphism, it is necessary and sufficient that $Y$ have the quotient topology determined by $f$.

The point that I don't understood is follows.

Let $q : X \rightarrow X /\sim$ be a quotient map.

Now consider $h(U) = \{ f(x) : [x]\in U\} = \{ f(x) : x \in q^{-1}(U) \} = f(q^{-1}(U))$, then textbook state 
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(h(U)) = f^{-1} ( f(q^{-1}(U))) = q^{-1}(U)
\end{align}

I have trouble with understanding the last equality. here by assumption $f$ is onto, what I know from set theory is for surjective $f$, I have $f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$  and for injective $f$, I have $f^{-1}(f(B)) = B$

So I have no idea how this holds

How the last equality can be valid?

Comment: What is $q$? The projection $X\to X/\sim$?

Comment: Are you missing any assumption? Is $f $ a homeomorphism? Or is it a quotient map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $q : X \to X/\sim$ is the canonical projection, and the quotient is the one induced by the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff f(x) = f(y)$.

We always have $f^{-1}f(B) \supset B$ for any $B$, and so it suffices to show that $f^{-1}f(q^{-1}(U)) \subset q^{-1}(U)$.

Take $x \in f^{-1}f(q^{-1}(U))$. This means that $f(x) \in f(q^{-1}(U))$ and so there exists $y \in X$ such that $q(y) \in U$ and $f(x) = f(y)$. By definition of the quotient, the latter implies $q(x) = q(y) \in U$ and so we get $x \in q^{-1}(U)$.

**Edit:** note that as long as $\sim$ is the equivalence relation induced by $f$, the former equality holds even when $f$ is not a quotient.